# Excel - Count if a name appears under a matching column (Header)

Tags: excel

I am trying to determine the appropriate excel Formula to count items only if the header matches and the row elements match an additional criteria.  I have done this before when Summing numbers (Sumifs), but not counting elements.  Spreadsheet has Time down the side ie. 1:00,2:00,3:00 and Dates across the top ie. 1/3/18  1/4/18 See Below:

Time   1/02/18   1/03/18   1/04/18
1:00   Joseph   Joseph   Nancy

2:00   Stephen  Joseph   Nancy

3:00   Jeffrey  Jeffrey  Jeffrey

4:00   George   George   George

Formula would answer the question on 1/3/18 how many hours did Joseph work?  Or on 1/4/18 how many Hours did Nancy work?  See below (I've used underscores to try and keep spacing reasonable:

_______1/3/18__1/4/18

Joseph ____2 _____0

Nancy  ____0 ______2

George ____1 _____1

Jeffrey _____1 _____1

[Picture of a like Excel Table:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH9TS.png)

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Nope, just an error when posting the question (too late at night I think).  Thanks for catching it!

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple [COUNTIF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function) in B2 (copied across and down) should work (based on your image **not** your question details) if you set up an additional sheet with the required labels for rows and columns:

```
=COUNTIF(Spreadsheet!B:B,$A2)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Yes it will count how many times the names appear, but it does not do a match on the date.